# Assertion error of a Test Case leads to failure of all subsequent test cases while executing the script in batch run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

Used Selenium WebDriver with Java
Used `softassertion` to assert the test case and have `softassert.assertAll()` in the end of each Test

While Executing Script in batch, Assertion of a Test case is failed as shown in the figure.[Actual Assertion Failed For This Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ6ja.png)
After that test case, all subsequent test cases got failed showing same assertion error as shown in figure.[All these Subsequent Tests got failed Showing Same Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eCOl.png)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
import utilities.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserCreationTest extends GetDriver {

    static int status;
    static String getUsername;
    static String getName;
    UserCreation userCreation = new UserCreation(driver, wait);
    ParamValues paramValues = new ParamValues();
    Common common = new Common(driver, wait);
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    JDBC_Connection db = new JDBC_Connection();
 @Test
    public void verifySelectPasswordPolicyDropdown() throws SQLException, 
ClassNotFoundException {

    CommonMethods.searchMenu(userCreation.menu);
    CommonMethods.clickOnMenu(userCreation.menu, userCreation.landingPage);
    CommonMethods.clickOnNewButton(userCreation.newButton);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(userCreation.pageLoad))).isDisplayed();

    List<WebElement> selectValue = driver.findElements(By.xpath(userCreation.selectValue));
    selectValue.get(0).click();

    List<WebElement> policyList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(userCreation.passwordPolicyList));
    int visiblePolicy = policyList.size();
    int getPolicyCount = Integer.parseInt(db.setDataBase(SQLQueries.getPasswordPolicy));
    softAssert.assertTrue(visiblePolicy == getPolicyCount, visiblePolicy + " is not equal to " + getPolicyCount);

    ResultSet getPolicy = db.returnResultSet(SQLQueries.searchPolicy);
    String getPolicyId = null;

    List<String> getTooltipValue = new ArrayList<>();
    while (getPolicy.next()) {
        getPolicyId = getPolicy.getString(1);
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(3));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(4));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(5).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(6).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(7).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(8).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(9).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(10).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(11).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(12).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(19).replace("1", "Yes").replace("0", "No"));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(13));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(14));
        getTooltipValue.add(getPolicy.getString(21));
        break;
    }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[0])).sendKeys(getPolicyId);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[1]))).isDisplayed();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[1])).click();
    softAssert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.tooltip)).isDisplayed());

    String[] tooltipVal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//DIV[@class='tooltip-inner']")).getText().split("\n");
    List<String> toolTipContent = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int n = 0; n < tooltipVal.length; n++) {
        String[] NewTooltip = tooltipVal[n].split(" - ");
        try {
            toolTipContent.add(NewTooltip[1]);
            //System.out.println(NewTooltip[1]);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(tooltipVal[n] + " is not available");
            toolTipContent.add(n, "No");
        }
    }
    //Compare DB vs UI Values
    softAssert.assertTrue(toolTipContent == getTooltipValue, toolTipContent + " is not equal to " + getTooltipValue);
    //A) No data found
    selectValue.get(0).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[0])).sendKeys(TestData.updateData);
    try {
        softAssert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.passwordPolicyList)).isDisplayed(), "No List Found for invalid Search");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Element not found");
    }
    //B) Valid Search
    String searchPolicy = db.setDataBase(SQLQueries.searchPolicy);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[0])).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[0])).sendKeys(searchPolicy);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(userCreation.selectSearchedPolicy[1]))).isDisplayed();
    softAssert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.passwordPolicyList)).isDisplayed(), "No List Found for valid search");
    softAssert.assertAll();
}
@Test
public void verifySelectLanguageDropdown() {
    CommonMethods.searchMenu(userCreation.menu);
    CommonMethods.clickOnMenu(userCreation.menu, userCreation.landingPage);
    CommonMethods.clickOnNewButton(userCreation.newButton);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(userCreation.pageLoad))).isDisplayed();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.selectLanguage)).click();

    List<WebElement> languageList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(userCreation.languageList));
    int visibleLanguage = languageList.size();
    System.out.println(visibleLanguage + " languages are available");

    //A) No data found
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.searchLanguage)).sendKeys(TestData.updateData);
    try {
        softAssert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.languageList)).isDisplayed(), "No Language List Found for invalid search");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Element not found");
    }

    //B) Valid Search
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.searchLanguage)).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.searchLanguage)).sendKeys(ParamValues.enterLanguage);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(userCreation.chooseSelectedLanguage))).isDisplayed();
    softAssert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.chooseSelectedLanguage)).isDisplayed(), "No Language list Found for valid search");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(userCreation.chooseSelectedLanguage)).click();
    softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

Please find the above Code
In this, Assertion of method verifySelectPasswordPolicyDropdown() gets failed at

```
//Compare DB vs UI Values
softAssert.assertTrue(toolTipContent == getTooltipValue, toolTipContent + " 
is not equal to " + getTooltipValue);
```

Below is the error for the failure

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
[2, 2, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, 3, 3, 30] is not equal to [2, 2, 
No, No, No, No, No, 5, No, No, No, 3, 3, 30] expected [true] but found 
[false]
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

After this, same error is shown with method verifySelectLanguageDropdown() and it is also failed

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To make it easier for others to help you out, would you be able to edit your question to include (in code blocks) the relevant code and errors to your problem. Images of code/errors are more difficult to work with than plain text. For more info, give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read.

Comment: Will you please share relevant code? You can try using [qaf](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) which provides inbuilt support for selenium webdriver [assertion and verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html)

Comment: @user861594  Please find the updated details related to the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: @Ekta screenshot shows the status code 400. It means one of your tests might have generated `bad request` which eventually passed to all the tests and all failed at the assertion.